# Как обновить WPF UI во время выполнения метода

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

Имеется C# WPF приложение использующее MVVM pattern и NuGet пакет Prism.Wpf. Некоторые методы во ViewModel выполняются продолжительное время. Если внутри такого метода использовать RaisePropertyChanged, то UI измениться только после завершения метода. Как обновлять интерфейс во время выполнения?

Comment: Так не выполняйте работу в UI потоке. Переходите в UI поток только в моменты обновления UI

Comment: Вот здесь ещё есть вариант как обновлять таки `UI` внутри циклов во `ViewModel` https://stackoverflow.com/a/10591314/8324991

Comment: Интерфейс не надо обновлять, ему надо не просто мешать обновляться. Например сделав свои операции асинхронными. Без кода тут мало что можно посоветовать, потому что решений куча, и какое из них нужно именно вам - загадка. И самое главное `продолжительное время` - что является причиной? Интенсивные вычисления? Обращение в сеть? В базу данных? Thread.Sleep? Покажите код. Быть может вам асинхронность нужна, быть может потоки, быть может и то и другое, быть может Producer/Consumer подойдет, или машина состояний, нужны ли семафоры, межпоточное взаимодействие с UI и т.д. Мой вопрос длиннее вашего.

Comment: Представьте, что ваш UI - просто фантик, который только лишь отображает данные. Ему не важно, что находится внутри. У конкретного контрола есть конкретное свойство, которое оно отображает или с которым взаимодействует и не более того. Операции, которые у вас выполняются внутри, не должны никак влиять на ваш UI. Допустим, у вас есть какая-то очень тяжёлая операция обработки данных, в конце выполнения которой, они выводятся на UI. Что это значит? Добавляем асинхронность или многопоточность (в зависимости от ситуации конкретной). По итогу выполнения этой сложной операции она...

Comment: ...только лишь присваивает определённому свойству некоторое значение, которое UI, благодаря INotifyPropertyChanged, отображает. Сложно ответить, что именно должно вам помочь без кода. Почему эта операция такая тяжёлая? Может её можно как-нибудь оптимизировать? Есть тонна предположений, но, пока не будет конкретики, вряд ли кто-то сможет дать чёткий ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Использую BackgroundWorker. Всё работает.